# Can't change permissions on ext4 sdcard

Tags: partitioning, permissions, mount, lubuntu

I'm running Lubuntu 20.04.2 LTS Release: 20.04 Codename: focal on an x86 mini-pc and everything works fine.
Since there is no so much free space on internal ssd I've inserted a ~64GB SDCard to use it as more space to storage data.
I'd like to use this card for docker containers/images but I can't chown/chmod the directories inside..

```
pippo@pippo-z83ii:/$ lsblk -f
NAME         FSTYPE LABEL UUID                                 FSAVAIL FSUSE% MOUNTPOINT
mmcblk0
├─mmcblk0p1  ext4         baabcddb-e943-40c3-b142-7b4ab31e2205   15,3G    31% /
├─mmcblk0p2  swap         740ac7f7-dc2e-4358-a82a-d062529dd574                [SWAP]
└─mmcblk0p3  vfat         64F2-CB58                                91M     8% /boot/efi
mmcblk0boot0
mmcblk0boot1
mmcblk2
└─mmcblk2p1  exfat        0123-4567                              58,2G     0% /media/pippo/0123-4567
pippo@pippo-z83ii:/$ sudo chown pippo:root /media/pippo/0123-4567/docker/
chown: changing ownership of '/media/pippo/0123-4567/docker/': Operation not permitted
pippo@pippo-z83ii:/$ ls media/ -Al
total 12
drwxr-x---  2 root root 4096 lug  3  2020 apt
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 lug  3  2020 cdrom
drwxrwxrwx+ 3 root root 4096 mar 14 12:29 pippo
pippo@pippo-z83ii:/$ sudo ls media/pippo/ -Al
total 128
drwxr-xr-x 3 pippo pippo 131072 mar 14 12:29 0123-4567
/dev/mmcblk2p1 on /media/pippo/0123-4567 type exfat (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,uid=1000,gid=1001,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,iocharset=utf8,namecase=0,errors=remount-ro,uhelper=udisks2)
```

1. Why is my sdcard automounted as /media/pippo/0123-4567 ?
2. How to fix chown pippo:root 0123-4567 ?

Comment: Why don't you have the SDCard using a *native* and POSIX compatible file-system?

Comment: @guiverc 
pippo@pippo-z83ii:/$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS
Release: 20.04
Codename: focal

Comment: sudo mount -l  shows this:
`/dev/mmcblk2p1 on /media/pippo/0123-4567 type exfat (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,uid=1000,gid=1001,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,iocharset=utf8,namecase=0,errors=remount-ro,uhelper=udisks2)`

Comment: @guiverc Can you tell me the steps to follow to format the card to a right POSIX filesystem? I also need the SD card be mounted at startup because I use as permanent space.

Comment: You should be able to format the card using *KDE Partition Manager*  (https://manual.lubuntu.me/stable/3/3.1/3.1.7/kde_partitionmanager.html), to have it automount, I'd add it to your *file-system-table* (ie. `/etc/fstab`).   If you need more you'll have to wait for someone else to help, I'm off to bed.